# Blurry pixel paint on scaled canvas drawBitmap on Samsung devices

Tags: android, canvas, pixel

Some users encountered blurry pixels issue on Samsung devices. I don't have any Samsung device to check, but there is no problems with phones I have.

I can't understand what is different on Samsung and why there is no issue with other devices! It will be very nice if someone could help me to understand!

Thank you!

[How it looks on samsung](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGTnV.jpg)

My code:

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    canvas.save();
    canvas.translate(imagePosition.getX(), imagePosition.getY());
    canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor);

    boolean hasBackground = backgroundImage != null;

    if (hasBackground) {

        canvas.drawBitmap(backgroundImage, 0, 0, backgroundPaint);

        if (currentMode != ColoringModeEnum.NONE && activity.getAppSettings().highlightActiveSquares) {
            canvas.drawBitmap(hintBitmap, 0, 0, paint);
        }
    }

    canvas.drawBitmap(coloringBitmap, 0, 0, paint);
    canvas.restore();
}


private final Paint paint = new Paint();
```

Comment: If you do a `setFilterBitmap(true)` on your `paint`, does that make it happen on your devices?

Comment: Thanks for response. Yes!  Blurry pixels appears on my device too. Should I use setting for Paints to make blurriness disappear for "issue encountered" devices?

Comment: Hmm. I'm having trouble believing Samsung would modify the default `Paint` object in that way. Surely you have some other library in your project that is messing with the `Paint`. If not, I think I'd have to recommend simply forcing `setFilterBitmap()` to false, and hope that fixes it.

Comment: I suppose my question is answered. I will contact users after I release new version to make sure all is ok! Thank you!

Comment: Well if it works, let me know and I will post an official answer.

Comment: After I set setFilterBitmap() to false and released an update the users who encountered the problem report that problem has gone away. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your bitmap looks filtered. To fix this, you can call:

`backgroundPaint.setFilterBitmap(false)`

The question then becomes, why does it only appear to do this on Samsung devices? Obviously, app programmers must be able to predict which state their `Paint` objects are in, otherwise their apps will break (as yours did).

So, I ran this past a few devices in my test lab. It appears that the default `isFilterBitmap()` setting (`FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG`) changed on API 29, although I'm unable to find it in the source code (if anyone can find it, or has more insight, please add a comment, or suggest an edit!)

```
Device                API level     isFilterBitmap() default
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Pixel 3 XL            29            true
Pixel 2 XL emulator   29            true
Pixel 2 XL emulator   28            false
Pixel 2 emulator      26            false
Samsung S6            25            false
Samsung S4            21            false
Droid RAZR            16            false
```