# If canvas.scale(x,y) then canvas.drawPath(path,paint) get blurry edges?

Tags: java, android, scale, android-canvas, pixel

I have something like finger pixel drawing.
Why, when i do this:

```
public class DrawViewPixel extends View {
Paint paint;
Path mPath;
Bitmap mBitmap;
Canvas mCanvas;


int  RESOLUTION, xBefore, yBefore;
float CANVAS_SIZE, CELL_SIZE;

public DrawViewPixel(Context context, int canvasSize ) {
    super(context);
    CANVAS_SIZE = canvasSize; //CANVAS_SIZE = 300dp
    RESOLUTION = 12;
    CELL_SIZE = CANVAS_SIZE/RESOLUTION;
    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setStrokeWidth(1);
    paint.setAntiAlias(false); 
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
    paint.setColor(Color.RED);
    mPath = new Path();
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.scale(CELL_SIZE,CELL_SIZE);
    canvas.drawPath(mPath,paint);
}
```

i see this:
[image]

But not this:
[image]

I tried many properties of paint and canvas, but ... :( Can someone tell me why?

Comment: On which Android version do you run your code? Might it be that issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16090607/blurry-offset-paths-when-canvas-is-scaled-under-hardware-acceleration

Comment: @3dmg thanks, it's almost what i was looking for. Like sad my grandmother: jast put on glasses :)

Comment: Might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60239696/blurry-pixel-paint-on-scaled-canvas-drawbitmap-on-samsung-devices